# Is it possible to have a Eidolon that is also a weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, summoner, improvised-weaponry

Are there any rules for using another character as a weapon? Specifically an Eidolon. From what little I can find on the topic the weapon PC would count as an improvised weapon of some club variety. Seeing as how the player can more or less dictate the appearance of an Eidolon, I really like the idea of mine being a sword. Swords of course enjoy being wielded.

As such I was wondering if there was anything that already exists in the rules that could help me out, maybe some evolution I missed or some esoteric spell or feat.

Basically, **What do I need to do to wield my Eidolon as a non-improvised sword**

Comment: I've voted to close as unclear, because I really don't understand what you're trying to do here.  Are you trying to have an intelligent magical sword that you can summon at will?  Are you trying to do some kind of cheesy combo that involves having an eidolon as a weapon?  It would be helpful in this case if you told us what you were trying to accomplish by haveing an eidolon as a weapon.

Comment: all of the above + curiosity. I want to know if there is a way to elevate the Eidolon, being wielded as a improvised weapon, to something more than a very poor club. This isn't for any specific mechanical effect, more to see if there are any effects that people can think of. The question is spurred by wanting an Eidolon that is shaped like a weapon and then using it a one because that sounds like a rad idea. If there is some meaning to it, rules-wise, that would be great as it would justify playing the idea, in this form, in an upcoming game.

Comment: Unfortunately, the kind of idea-generating spitballing that you're looking for is not a great fit for this site.  You might be better served by asking this kind of question on a [forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: "Seeing as how the player can more or less dictate the appearance of an Eidolon" - how does this work with the Eidolon's Base Forms? Some explanation of why you think this is possible would make it easier to understand your question.

Comment: 'you should answer the question before you ask the question' - helpful as usual, guys.

Comment: If my edit changed the meaning of your question, feel free to roll it back or let me know how/that it was problematic and I'll fix it.  Also, welcome to the site!  Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help]

Comment: It's a shame it's not 3.5e. You would then train your Eidolon to be a Monk and therefore count as a weapon.

Answer (score 4):

### Sure, but it's weird.

Eidolons have *base forms* - their base set of stats and starting evolutions.  You can't, without fiat or class options I am unaware of, trade out those evolutions.

So you can totally have a sword-shaped eidolon, but it's Medium size (aka the size of a person) and has arms and legs and fangs and stuff.  Note that it doesn't need to necessarily have obvious eyes or anything - it simply must have the evolutions listed on it's base form.  It's arms or legs could 'fold' into it's body, and it could use disguise to appear like a normal (or magical) Huge-sized greatsword or something, but to function as limbs and use it's natural attacks, they do need to be.. identifiable as such.

Using something that isn't a listed weapon as a weapon follows the Improvised Weapon rules, nearly always.  Improvised weapons are not particularly good weapons.  However, [Catch Off-Guard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/catch-off-guard-combat) and [Improved Catch Off-Guard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/rogue-genius-games/combat-feats/improved-catch-off-guard-combat) (3P), improve improvised weapon use considerably - mostly, though, for rogues.  At the very least, if you're taking this path, you can eliminate the -4 penalty.

The simplest solution to wanting to do this is, as always, houserules.  Your GM can rule that you can summon the sword, and it can just function as a sword (say with a scaling enhancement bonus like the Bladebound Magus' Black Blade), or that it functions as a sword until it wants to act on it's own and make natural attacks, or even allow it to make natural attacks using sword damage alongside your attack routine.  I will **heavily stress** that this is **not more powerful** than the standard summoner, since it involves the summoner going into melee (a place summoners typically don't want to go into) and eidolons are already extremely powerful.  Even the 'natural attacks + summoner's attacks, using the sword' option isn't more powerful, as it means there's a chance the summoner himself could die.

If you want to stay within the rules as written, I hesitate to bring it up, but the Synthesist Summoner could be what you're looking for.  It's a Summoner who wears their summoned eidolon like a suit, becoming a monster when they summon it.  If your eidolon is just a sword(or, a copy of you holding a sword), and summoning it just grants you power and skill beyond your norm, you would look like you holding a sword when you summon ('synthesise') the eidolon.  Yet have the strength, speed, slam attacks or whatever that the eidolon has.

Comment: Note that the creature should probably count as grappled.